# How to set a counter for spawning enemies passing a certain point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, 2d, unityscript

I am making a game in unity where there are enemies spawning horizontally in the left direction. I wrote a piece of code for the enemy prefab that when it passes a position , the counter will increase by one. and if 5 enemies passed the point , a game over scene will appear.
When I run the scene , the count is not incremented !

Here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public int count=0;

     public void update()
     {
         if (GameObject.Find("bunny").transform.position.x == -3.0f)
          {
             count = +1;
             if (count == 5)
             {
                 Application.LoadLevel ("gameOver");
             }
         }
     }

 }
```

and here is the code for enemy movement :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour {

     public float speed ;

     void Update () {

         transform.Translate(-Vector2.right*speed*(Time.deltaTime));

     }
 }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

modify :

```
count = +1; =>  count++;
```

and

```
if (GameObject.Find("bunny").transform.position.x == -3.0f)
```

Floating point comparison is not recommanded. So modifying the code will be better.

```
if (((int)GameObject.Find("bunny").transform.position.x) == -3)
```

and cache finding variable as a member variable in the class, because it's so expensive to find object in a scene.

```
GameObject bunny = GameObject.Find("bunny");
```

Answer (score 0):

Jinbom Heo's answer is correct but I'd also like to point out that in this line:

```
if (GameObject.Find("bunny").transform.position.x == -3.0f)
```

there may be some times position.x wouldn't equal exactly 3.0f. Better change it to:

```
if (GameObject.Find("bunny").transform.position.x < -3.0f)
```

As for the caching part, it should look something like this:

```
 public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public int count=0;
     GameObject bunny;

     void Start(){
         bunny = GameObject.Find("bunny");
     }

     public void update()
     {
         if (bunny.transform.position.x < -3.0f){
             // ...
         }
     }
 }
```